# How to open fancy box images thumbs using ajax?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

When I load images with AJAX then I click on image but image thumbs not show at first time. How can I handle that?

```
$(document).on("click", ".fancybox", function() {
  $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    toolbar: false, // disable toolbar
    thumbs: {
      autoStart: true,
      hideOnClose: true
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you use code like this, where does it come from? I have seen this pattern multiple times and it is completely wrong.

So, let's break your code apart to see what you are doing here -

`$(document).on("click", ".fancybox", function() {` - you assign click event to every element having class name `.fancybox`. That click event will do the following:

`$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({` - here you assign click event to every element having data-attribute `data-fancybox`; and that click event will start fancybox with custom options.

You see the problem? Remove `$(document).on("click", ".fancybox", function() {` part and it should work fine. Alternatively you could use `$.fancybox.open()` method that would immediately start fancybox (instead of assigning click event using `$(selector).fancybox()`)